# Prometheus node exporter text files

Tags: raspberry-pi, prometheus, grafana

I have my frist prometheus and grafana builds running in docker. I have a raspberry pi with a temp sensor attached and produces out put to a text file like this.

```
date                 temp
8/20/200 08:20:31 am, 89
8/20/200 08:25:31 am, 90
```

I am sure this is possible to read in to prometheus I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to write a prometheus 'client' which will read the temp sensor and respond to 'pull' requests (http gets) from prometheus.  There are [libraries](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) to help.

Comment: If you're unable to publish the sensor metrics directly using an HTTP server on the Pi, then see [grok_exporter](https://github.com/fstab/grok_exporter)